# Rails/Passenger/Nginx: Redirecting www.domain.com to domain.com (to prevent SSL warning)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, nginx, passenger

I have an SSL certificate on domain.com, but if a user goes to https://www.domain.com, it throws a 'wrong domain' security error.

I'm just wondering on best practice for redirecting all traffic from www.domain.com to domain.com. I tried throwing a rewriterule into passenger, but it still seems to suffer the same problem.

Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fairly easy to do that with nginx..

```
server {
  listen 80; 
  server_name www.example.com;
  rewrite ^(.*)$ https://example.com$1 permanent;
}

server {
  listen 80; 
  server_name example.com;

  # etc
```

That will redirect all requests hitting `www.example.com` to `https://example.com`

Comment: `rewrite ^ https://example.com$1? permanent;` is better. See http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls